# How can I prevent search engines from returning a URL with variables?

Tags: asp.net, url, search-engine, bing, urlvariables

We have a website that contains encrypted user information in the URL.  For example:

www.mysite.com/default.aspx?xs=ew0KICA

Our client reported Bing.com is coming up with that full URL (including the encrypted user information) and is allowing data to be viewed without logging in.  How can I prevent Bing (or any search engine) from returning the URL with the user information?

Also, please note that I did not design this site so I'd ask you to avoid comments such as "you shouldn't pass user information that way."  It's not how I would have done it, but I need to fix it with minimal time allocated to me to do so.  I just need some help figuring out why Bing did this and how to stop it.  Thanks!

Comment: `you shouldn't pass user information that way` is the **correct** answer.  You **need** authentication.   `robots.txt` can stop a little bit of this, but is nowhere near enough.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning robots.txt.  I looked into it and we're going to try it.